# Jquery selectable: Allow multiselect just for one class/type

Tags: jquery, html, multi-select, jquery-ui-selectable

I have a table with an ordered list. The ordered list contains selectable timestamps. One table entry "td" is a day. (I am programming a web calendar).

```
<td class="day"><div class="scroll">

        <ol class="timelist">

            <li id="2017-10-27_14:41" class="ui-selectee">14:41</li>
            <li id="2017-10-27_15:28" class="ui-selectee">15:28</li>
            <li id="2017-10-27_16:00" class="ui-selectee">16:00</li>
            <li id="2017-10-27_08:00" class="ui-selectee">08:00</li>
            <li id="2017-10-27_09:00" class="ui-selectee">09:00</li>
            <li id="2017-10-27_12:01" class="ui-selectee">12:01</li>

        </ol>

</div>
</td>
```

This is the jquery code I have:

```
<script type= "application/javascript">

         $(document).ready(function(){

         $( ".timelist" ).on( "mousedown", function ( e ) {
        e.metaKey = true;
        } ).selectable();

        }); 

 </script>
```

Right now, if I already selected one timestamp and click on another it also selects the second one. Thats exactly what i want and it works like a charm.

But additionally I want to select days. But if I already selected one timestamp and click on a day, my program shall cancel the selection of timestamps and it shall select the clicked day. If one day is selected and I click on another day, it shall mark this day ALSO (2 days selected and so on). But if I already selected a day or more, and I now click on a timestamp, the program shall cancel the selection of the days.

What I want to say is: "Just enable multiselect on elements with the same type/HTML-class".

How do I do that?

Comment: Using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `.bind()` let you add a sub-selector as you are asking for, your problem is that you are binding the very same function to all those selectable elements instead of having different groups of them

Comment: Ok, I changed it in my file. Thanks. But can you give me an example? How do I tell my program to selecting further?

Answer (score 0):

Use the "ui-widget-content" class instead of "ui-selectee".

Comment: I didnt use it myself. My HTML file has automatically added the class "ui-selectee". I guess its because of the selectable() function. Can you be a bit more specific and give me and example?

Comment: Check out this http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ZfevM/7/ from Nick Craver.